# Is it offensive to use "Red Tape" in a sentence?

Tags: email, business-language

I need to reply to an email and I wanted to clarify to the other person that:

> I understand exactly what needs to be done on the technical side but
>   I'm not familiarized with the red tape involved in the process.

Would that be, somehow, offensive?

Comment: It is a bit offensive to accuse someone of using 'red tape' since it suggests they are obstructing progress for some spurious reason.  I think I would only employ the term if I had entirely given up any hope of getting anywhere with someone. Otherwise it might produce the contrary effect to the one you want.

Comment: In your context it probably *is* "offensive". Well, that's probably putting it a bit strong, but "red tape" is *always* used "negatively", and obviously you're emailing someone who is *responsible* for the ***administrative procedures*** involved, so you're effectively describing their job in negative terms.

Comment: Yes, if you mean exactly 'red tape' (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_tape) and, No, if you just mean 'all the paperwork/ attendant bother/ ...'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Red tape* could be offensive in that it's often used as a value laden term, implying unnecessary or excessive regulatory or managerial requirements. From the point of view of those responsible for that regulation or management it could be seen as a criticism or disparagement of their work and its seriousness. Though in your example it seems a fairly lighthearted euphemism.

Comment: Red-tape *has* a negative connotation. However, it's not clear if the OP means by the expression.